# Можно ли вызвать конструктор в методе жизненного цикла?

Tags: reactjs, классы, конструктор

```
class AppContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getBgImage(this.season)
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.season = 'winter';
    this.style = {
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.props.bgImage + ')',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='app-wrapper' style={this.style}>
      {this.props.isFetching ? <Preloader /> : <App season = {this.season}/>}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

В методе жизненного цикла `componentDidMount` вызывается функция, которая изменяет state. И в зависимости от свойств state у меня должен меняться объект style, описанный в конструкторе. Но конструктор вызывается раньше, чем componentDidMount, поэтому свойство style остается underfined. Как мне сделать так, чтобы свойство style менялось после того, как вызовется функция из componentDidMount?

Стоит отметить, что функция `getBgImage()` встречается не только в этом участке кода, поэтому просто объявить style в `componentDidMount` не получится.

Comment: Чем плохо обновить `style` в `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: Потому, что функция getBgImage(), которая меняет state, вызывается ещё и в других местах программы. Соответственно, нужно, чтобы при каждом изменении стейта менялся и объект style. Я вот не знаю как это правильно сделать, потому что,насколько я знаю, constructor вызывается всего один раз

Comment: Замените `getBgImage` своей версией, которая будет обновлять `style`.

Comment: Да проблема в том, что эта функция делает запрос к серверу, выбирает рандомный элемент и т.д. Вряд ли так получится сделать. Я в общем хочу узнать, можно ли сделать так, чтобы переменная в классе как-то обновлялась?Допустим, если изменились props, то конструктор заново вызовется и изменит значение переменной?

Comment: У вас есть в коде сколько-то мест, где меняется `props`. Во все эти места нужно встроить обновление `style`. Это можно сделать, иногда понадобится фантазия. Покажите конкретный код, чтобы его можно было доработать.

Comment: Я уже решил проблему с помощью React Hooks(useEffect)

Comment: Хорошая технология именно для такого рода проблем!